# VSCode with Bitbucket and JIRA

Tags: visual-studio-code, bitbucket, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I’m having issues linking my JIRA and Bitbucket accounts to my VSCode. I’ve downloaded the Atlassian extension and followed the steps provided here:

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/get-started-with-vs-code/

However, my Atlassian settings page in VSCode is blank.

If I try and click the below links in the side panel:

‘Authenticate with Bitbucket to view pull requests’
Or
‘Please login to Jira’
The links don’t go anywhere.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Visual code version 1.67.2

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Tried uninstalling and reinstalling.  
*** VS Code Settings: 
Version: 1.70.0 (user setup)
Commit: da76f93349a72022ca4670c1b84860304616aaa2
Date: 2022-08-04T04:38:16.462Z
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363

*** Extension: atlassian.atlascode, version 2.10.12

Comment: I also created this issue: https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/atlascode/issues/782/atlassian-settings-tab-is-blank-after